# need assistance on mongoose user verification

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose

I am new to mongoDB and mongoose. But what I am trying to do is be able to authenticate the user I have stored in my database by their email, if a user was successfully retrieved the I will compare the password they wrote with the hashed password stored in the database

this is what I have for my Schema

**UserSchema**

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true }, //require makes it so that the fields can't be left blank
  lastName: {type: String, required: true},
  emailAddress: {type: String, required: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true}      
});
var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I am using the basic-auth package in my routes.js file in order to test this api in postman, this middlewhere function check if a user password matches what they have on authorizatio header  on postman vs what they have on the req.body

```
//This middle-where function will authenticate users
const authenticateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  let message = null;

  // Parse the user's credentials from the Authorization header.
  const credentials = auth(req);

  // If the user typed the Authorization header...
  if (credentials) {
    console.log(credentials)
    // Attempt to retrieve the user from the data store
    // by their email (i.e. the user's "key"
    // from the Authorization header).
    const user = User.find({emailAddress: credentials.name}) 

    // If a user was successfully retrieved from the data store...
    if (user) {
      // Use the bcryptjs npm package to compare the user's password typed
      // (from the Authorization header) to the user's password sent in req.body in postman
      const authenticated = bcryptjs
        .compareSync(credentials.pass, req.body.password);
      // If the passwords match...
      if (authenticated) {
        console.log(`Authentication successful for user: ${req.body.firstName} `);

        // Then store the retrieved user object on the request object
        // so any middleware functions that follow this middleware function
        // will have access to the user's information.
        req.currentUser = user;
      } else {
        message = `Authentication failure for user:  ${req.body.firstName} `;
      }
    } else {
      message = `User not found for email: ${credentials.name}`;
    }
  } else {
    message = 'Auth header not found';
  }

  // If user authentication failed...
  // Return a response with a 401 Unauthorized HTTP status code.
  if (message) {
    console.warn(message);

    // Return a response with a 401 Unauthorized HTTP status code.
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Access Denied' });
  } else {
    // Or if user authentication succeeded...
    // Call the next() method.
    next();
  }
};
```

this is my get route to get users

```
//GET /api/users 200, THIS WORKS IN POSTMAN
//This Route returns the currently authenticated user
router.get('/users', authenticateUser, (req, res) => {
  //within the route handler, the current authenticated user's information is retrieved from the Request object's currentUser property:
  const user = req.currentUser;
//we use the Response object's json() method to return the current user's information formatted as JSON:
  res.json({
    firstName: user.firstName

  });
});
```

where I am really struggling is on the authentication, when I try to login in postman even with the right credentials I get this error in the terminal `Authentication failure for user` can someone help, for reference this is my repo https://github.com/SpaceXar20/rest_api-mongo-p9

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are comparing the parsed password from the request against a password you retrieve from the body of the request:

```
    if (user) {
      // Use the bcryptjs npm package to compare the user's password typed
      // (from the Authorization header) to the user's password sent in req.body in postman
      const authenticated = bcryptjs
        .compareSync(credentials.pass, req.body.password);
```

what I think you want is to compare the password from the header against the hash stored on your user

```
    if (user) {
      // Use the bcryptjs npm package to compare the user's password typed
      // (from the Authorization header) to the user's password sent in req.body in postman
      const authenticated = bcryptjs
        .compareSync(credentials.pass, user.password);
```

Comment: yes! thats exacly what I want to achieve, I made the suggested changes in my code, but then when I tested on postman I got this error: `{
    "error": {
        "message": "Illegal arguments: string, undefined"
    }
}`

Comment: that's because ```const user = User.find({emailAddress: credentials.name}) ``` isn't actually the user but a mongoose query object. Easiest is to do ```const user = await User.find({emailAddress: credentials.name})```, don't forget about ```const authenticateUser = async (req, res, next) => .... ``` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: I tried your suggestion like `const authenticateUser = async (req, res, next) =>  {
  let message = null;

  // Parse the user's credentials from the Authorization header.
  const credentials = auth(req);

  // If the user typed the Authorization header...
  if (credentials) {
    console.log(credentials)
    // Attempt to retrieve the user from the data store
    // by their email (i.e. the user's "key"
    // from the Authorization header).
    const user = await User.find({emailAddress: credentials.name})`

Comment: And I get this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never :), so you should use `await` before query or use `.then .catch` like this:

```
const user = await User.find({emailAddress: credentials.name})
```

after that you should compare password in db(user.password) with password in body

```
const authenticated = bcryptjs.compareSync(user.password, req.body.password);
```

or use

```
const authenticated = await bcryptjs.compare(user.password, req.body.password);
```